# Rails - how to link to assets outside the app directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I'm brand new to Rails. I installed the Zurb foundation front-end framework as described here: http://www.zurb.com/article/814/yetify-your-rails-new-foundation-gem-and-

When I open app/assets/stylesheets/application.css I find this auto-generated code:

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in      this directory
* and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
* the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
*= require_self
*= require foundation
*= require_tree . 
*/
```

However, this line in my view

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
```

does not load the file zurb_foundation/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation/index.css I created:

```
couldn't find file 'foundation'
(in /Users/migu/railsapps/maneki1/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:6)
```

How can I make it load the file and all CSS files I put under zurb_foundation/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation/? Thanks...

Comment: Just tried to follow this instructions https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails/blob/master/README.markdown and didn't work either. I think it has to do with me being completely new to Rails. I can navigate to this directory .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/zurb-foundation-2.1.0 but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to restart the webserver before Rails picks up the new assets from the zurb-foundation gem. Once restarted, it should just work.

Also, you can check the zurb-foundation assets are correctly found from the rails console. At the command prompt, enter "rails c", and then "Rails.application.config.assets.paths" (both commands minus the quotes). You should see something like:

```
=> ["/Users/MYUSER/appPath/app/assets/images", "/Users/MYUSER/appPath/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/MYUSER/appPath/app/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/MYUSER/appPath/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/MYUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.19/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/MYUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/zurb-foundation-2.1.0/vendor/assets/images", "/Users/MYUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/zurb-foundation-2.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/MYUSER/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/zurb-foundation-2.1.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets"]
```

Note you might need to do some extra work to get the assets deployed on production.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solve similar issue based on this thread https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/834
Added compass-rails gem in Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'compass-rails'
```

Run:

```
bundle install
```

Dont' forget to restart the web-server and magic will happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this directive to your `application.css` file:

```
 *= require_directory ./foundation
```

Or you can use the `foundation-rails` gem.

Comment: Thanks! I changed to:  *= require_directory ./foundation
and it says "require_tree argument must be a directory"

Comment: Just to clarify: do you have your foundation stylesheets in the `app/assets/stylesheets/foundation` directory ?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply. Yes, they are in app/assets/stylesheets/foundation.