# show image using absolute path rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

For Ruby on Rails   I want to use

```
  <img src =../../../photo/1.PNG >
```

to  show some images stored outside my app folder. I use this and use .. to point out where image it it , But it does not work。 I use Win7, Is there anyone could help me ?

I have a MVC named "showcase" generated by scaffold, and I wanna to have the same showcase in two apps.
In app1: showcase (where I wanna to share the images)model: house is the image name.

```
class Showcase < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :house,:sequence

  has_attached_file :house, :whiny => false,
                    :styles => {  :large => "350x300>",
                                  :medium => "120x100>",
                                  :thumb => "50x50>"}
end
```

then the images will be uploaded in the folder: public/systems/showcases/houses/000/000/0001/1.PNG

in app2. I create a showcase model with migration. and use ActiveResources share the database between app1 and app2. but app2 can not configure paperclip type.

```
class Showcase < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://localhost:3000"
end
```

how can I in app2, call images uploaded from app1.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370915/rails-how-to-link-to-assets-outside-the-app-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your trying to really share images between applications, and they are uploads and not static assets then create a systems folder somewhere else, then make the system folders in each app a symlink to the share folder. That way your not having crazy url paths, and they both can asses it, and you wont end up with dupes or mismatches.

Comment: thank you for your answer,it looks reasonable, I am an entry bird in ror, could you please tell me in detail..I have edit my question above.

Comment: Its pretty simple, instead of having a system folder in each app, have a 'system' folder else ware and then in each app have symbolic link from where the systems folder would be to your new 'system' folder else where. That way they are sharing the same upload folder. You can also do this using an service like Amazon S3 which paperclip supports.

Comment: yes, I work it out!all the images could show up now, thank you sososo much:)

Answer (score 0):

You should really use the rails assets pipeline if you are using rails 3 or above. Put your images in app/assets/images and call the rails functions that gives you url to the assets e.g.  <%= image_tag "rails.png" %>.

For more detail read the following guideline:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: but the images are located in another app's fold like: public/systems/images/1.png(where they must be there). because I wanna to share the same parts of my two rails apps. do you know whether rails permits showing images which outside of current app?

Comment: it does not allow. The root url is referring to the directory of your application. You simply cannot go beyond your root location. I would suggest making duplications of your images to each of your apps since they are separate apps.

Comment: Also, if you really have to do so, the public directory should not be included in the url. e.g. try /systems/images/1.png instead of public/systems/images/1.png